# How to create a web page with CSS and JS so it acts like UITabBar (framework?)

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, css, web

So we've decided to create a down and dirty `Android` version to a working `iOS` app.
Since we don't code in Java and resources are limited, we thought of creating a `responsive` web version of the app, that emulates the app's environment more or less, but keeps most of the functionality. 
I should note that we haven't programmed `responsive` web pages before. we know there are media queries and functionalities for many different devices, though.

The idea was to create an Android app that uses a `webView` which is hardcoded to be a responsive web page. To the user we hope the result should be app-like.
We need the screen to look like this:

[image: Two windows are shown, and displayed according to the choice of the user]

so that when the user presses **`A`** - the `A` screen would show, and when **`B`** is pressed, `B` is shown.

**`A`** shows a scrollable list of items

[image: A shows a scrollable list]

**`B`** shows a some buttons, pressing these buttons would change a value that is sent via a **`web reuest`**.

[image: B shows some buttons]

We need something to help us come up with buttons, presses, screen resizing, events fired...
Is there any framework that we can use to accomplish a task like this? 
I was thinking of using jQuery, changing the visibility of the `<div>`s for the main screen. Of course it would take a graphic designer to make these buttons, and writing it all.
But is there any framework that is made for this? (We need the code!).
there will also be requests that are sent to the server and responses will be in JSON, so display `A` can be populated accordingly.

We need an answer that would target us to a solution that fulfills this functionality so we can go ahead and code the rest of the project.

Thanks!

Comment: You could take a look at meteor.com or angular.js!

Comment: bootstrap is good as far as responsiveness and playing with grids goes...

Comment: We have the same problem here. Please let us know where you eventually went! :)

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at Ionic, it's a framework that would be ideal for this purpose. http://ionicframework.com/

Once installed, you can use their cli tool to generate an app with an empty tabbed based application like so: `ionic start {appName} tabs`.

After you've completed your app you can run `ionic build android` to build the app.